# Unsupervised Sentiment Analysis pycaret

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, pycaret

Is it possible to conduct unsupervised sentiment analysis with Pycaret library if you have an unlabel dataset?

Any valid alternative and suggestion will be appreciated too